# Bower, Bootstrap and sass-rails gem, error: "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bower

In short I am trying to find out why I get the error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap
```

This is the full description:

1) I am managing my Javascript libraries using Bower, so I put bootstrap dependency inside the bower.js:

```
   ... 
   "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3"
    }
   ...
```

and I inserted in application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')
```

2) Rails4 is using the gem 'sass-rails' to manage Sass:

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

3) I also added

```
@import "bootstrap";

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}
```

to make bootstrapt-compatible with the rails-forms
(see https://gorails.com/blog/trying-out-bootstrap-3-0)

---

What I get is the error:

> **File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.**

Apart from the specific error, It would be really appreciate an explanation about **Bower** and **sass-rails** can collaborate together without problem (I didn't find any good resource on the web).

Answer (score 0):

Open your `/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file and add the following line:

```
*= require bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss
```

The `application.css` file must contain the directives which indicate which resources should be loaded by your application.